# Use UNION clause with ORDER BY for single query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with data like this.

```
Id       PId         Device             Status          Type      Created_Date
===      ===         ======             ======          ====      ============
1         2           1                  today          High      2012-04-12 08:11:51.583
2         2           4                  today          Medium    2012-04-02 01:39:52.393
3         3           5                  today          Medium    2012-04-02 01:10:02.443
4         2           6                  today          High      2012-04-02 01:05:25.063
5         2           3                  today          High      2012-04-02 01:03:08.360
6         2           7                  today          High      2012-04-02 01:02:57.093
7         2           2                  today          High      2012-04-02 00:22:37.807
```

Now, I want the records of Device 6 and 7 always on the top of the record set with descending order of created date. And records with device except 6 and 7 order by Type and Created Date Descending after the records of device type 6 and 7.

So the desired result is like below :

```
Id       PId         Device             Status          Type      Created_Date
===      ===         ======             ======          ====      ============
4         2           6                  today          High      2012-04-02 01:05:25.063
6         2           7                  today          High      2012-04-02 01:02:57.093
1         2           1                  today          High      2012-04-12 08:11:51.583
5         2           3                  today          High      2012-04-02 01:03:08.360
7         2           2                  today          High      2012-04-02 00:22:37.807
2         2           4                  today          Medium    2012-04-02 01:39:52.393
```

I have used the query as below :

```
select * from TblAlert where PId=2 and ( Device=6 OR Device=7) and ( Status='Today' or Status=0)
UNION
Select * from TblAlert Where  PId=2 and ( Device<>6 OR Device<>7)and (Status='Today' or Status=0)
order by Type,Created_Date desc
```

but its not working as it is applying order by clause on whole record set.

Can anybody help me regarding this please?

Comment: When you are using `UNION` to combine the results into one table using two queries `ORDER BY` clause does not work on complete result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it my self by Using Table variable as

```
DECLARE @Records TABLE
(
   Id  int,
   PId int,
   Device int,
   Status Alert_Type varchar(10),
   Type Alert_Type varchar(5), 
   Created_Date DateTime
); 

INSERT @Records 
    SELECT Id, PId, Device, Status,Type,Created_Date FROM 
        TblAlert 
    WHERE 
        PId =2
        AND Device IN (6,7) 
        AND ( Status='Today' or Status=0) 
    ORDER BY 
        Created_Date DESC; 

INSERT @Records 
    SELECT Id, PId, Device, Status,Type,Created_Date FROM 
        TblAlert 
    WHERE 
        PId =2
        AND Device NOT IN (6,7) 
        AND ( Status='Today' or Status=0) 
    ORDER BY 
        Type, Created_Date DESC; 

SELECT * FROM @Records;
```

Comment: **this is not how to solve this problem**  you are getting lucky that the database is returning the rows in the order you inserted them.    The only way to guarantee that you will get a consistent ordering is to use an ORDER BY, which you do not use.  You should look at using a CASE in the ORDER BY like @Mikael Eriksson does in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
select *
from TblAlert 
where PId=2 and ([Status]='Today' or [Status]='0')
order by case when Device in (6, 7) then 0 else 1 end,
         case when Device in (6, 7) then [Type] else '' end,
         Created_Date
```